# XMLHttpRequest() infinite loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The intention of the code below is to use Ajax to repeatedly obtain a PHP query result until that result is "6".

It is working accept that the script continues to run after the result of "6" is received when my CPU fan begins to roar loudly and, after several seconds, the "Loading..." message begins to flash on and off.

Ideas?

```
  function refreshData(){
  var display = document.getElementById("content");
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_status.php");
  //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      display.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        var test_response = this.responseText;
    } else {
      display.innerHTML = "Loading...";
    };
      if (this.responseText != "6") {                            
          refreshData();                        
      }  
  }
}
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
 $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=kevin234") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
        set_time_limit(0);    
        $result = pg_query('select max(num_files), max(file_num) from status');
        $num_files = pg_fetch_row($result);

echo "max_file_num = " . $num_files[1];
?>
```

And refreshData() is called from this code:

```
 var upload = function(files) {
                var formData = new FormData(),
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                    x;

                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
                //xhr.addEventListener("load", refreshData, false);
                //xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                //xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);        

                for(x = 0; x < files.length; x = x +1) {
                    formData.append('file[]', files[x]);                            
                }
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);      
                    displayUploads(data);
                }
                xhr.open('post', 'ids_v0.00_progress_bar.php');
                xhr.send(formData);

                function progressHandler (event) {
                    document.getElementById("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
                    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;             
                    if (event.loaded = event.total) {
                        refreshData();     
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is working accept that the script continues to run after the result of "6"

You need to move the re-calling of the function inside the `onreadystatechange` success of the `xmlhttp` call. That way one request is send at a time, not hundreds.

```js
function refreshData() {
  var display = document.getElementById("content");
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_status.php");
  //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      display.innerHTML = this.responseText;
      var test_response = this.responseText;
      if (this.responseText != "6") {
        refreshData();
      }
    } else {
      display.innerHTML = "Loading...";
    };

  }
}
```

**Why the change**

The problem with your code is that your website will continue to send requests on the side, regardless of the `responseText` value. The only thing the `responseText != "6"` is doing is check if that instance of a request should send another. The conditional re-sending of the request has to happen when one request is done, i.e. in the `if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)`.

Comment: If that solves your problem, please mark my solution as accepted by clicking the "Checkmark" on the left side of my answer.

Comment: _"You need to move the re-calling of the function inside..."_ - An explanation of the "why" would make this answer complete.

Comment: Correct, it has been added.

Comment: _"regardless of the `responseText` value"_ vs. `if(this.responseText != "6")` O.o

Comment: Edited one more time now.